# ASP.Net mvc & Angularjs page refresh and 404 error comes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am learning **Angularjs**. so i implement a small project along with angular js, angularJs routing and asp.net mvc5. i am using VS2013 IDE.

Angular js part is working as expected but when i refresh the page then i am getting 404 error.

here is my MVC controller code.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Students()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult GetCourse()
    {
        //string updatedata = p1 + " welcome";
        //string[] Courses = { "C#", "VB.Net", "SQL", "RDBMS", "ReactJs" };
        //return Json(Courses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        List<course> crs = new List<course>();
        crs.Add(new course { Name = "C#" });
        crs.Add(new course { Name = "VB.Net" });
        crs.Add(new course { Name = "SQL" });
        crs.Add(new course { Name = "RDBMS" });
        crs.Add(new course { Name = "ReactJs" });
        crs.Add(new course { Name = "MongoDb" });
        crs.Add(new course { Name = "PHP" });
        return Json(crs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        //return new JsonResult { Data = crs, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }

    public ActionResult GetStudents()
    {
        List<Students> std = new List<Students>();
        std.Add(new Students {ID=1, Name = "John",Country="UK" });
        std.Add(new Students { ID = 2, Name = "Sam", Country = "USA" });
        std.Add(new Students { ID = 3, Name = "Andrew", Country = "USA" });
        std.Add(new Students { ID = 4, Name = "Dibyendu", Country = "India" });
        std.Add(new Students { ID = 5, Name = "Arijit", Country = "India" });
        return Json(std, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public class course
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Students
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

My route.config code

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is my MVC layout page where i added all js path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="DemoApp">
<head>
    <title>{{Title}}</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/sample.css")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h2>Header</h2>
    </header>
    <section>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/course">Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="/students">Students</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
            <div>
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Footer</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var GetCoursesUrl = '@Url.Action("GetCourses", "Home")';
    </script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-route.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Script.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my js script file where angular module & controllers are there.

```
/// <reference path="_references.js" />
var app = angular.module("DemoApp", ["ngRoute"])
                .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
                    $routeProvider
                    .when('/', { // This is for reditect to another route
                        redirectTo: function () {
                            return '/home';
                        }
                    })
                    .when("/home",
                    {
                        templateUrl: "Template/Home.html",
                        controller: "homeController"
                    })
                    .when("/course",
                    {
                        templateUrl: "Template/Course.html",
                        controller: "courseController"
                    })
                    .when("/students",
                    {
                        templateUrl: "Template/Students.html",
                        controller: "studentController"
                    })
                    //.otherwise({
                    //    templateUrl: '/Template/Error.html',
                    //    controller: 'ErrorController'
                    //})
                    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!'); // This is for Hashbang Mode
                    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

                })
                .controller("homeController", function($scope)
                {
                    $scope.Message = "Home Page!!";
                    $scope.Title = "Home";
                })
                .controller("courseController", function ($scope, $http) {
                    //$scope.Courses = ["C#", "VB.Net", "SQL", "RDBMS"];
                    $scope.Title = "Courses";
                    $http({
                        url: "/Home/GetCourse",
                        method: 'GET'
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        //$log.info(response.data);
                        $scope.Courses = response.data;
                    });
                })
                .controller("studentController", function ($scope, $http) {
                    //$scope.Students = ["John", "Sam", "Mac", "Jeff"];
                    $scope.Title = "Students";
                    $http({
                        url: "/Home/GetStudents",
                        method: 'GET'
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                        //$log.info(response.data);
                        $scope.Students = response.data;
                    });
                })
```

my project is working. the only problem is when i refresh the page then 404 error is coming.

i have this url rewrite in config file which i commented now.

```
  <!--<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>-->
```

i commented because the above url rewrite rule blocking the $http call. when commented then **$http call start working**.

i also had a catchall route in . route.config file but that also did not help me to resolve page reload problem.
this is my catchAll route in route.config file which is commented so far now.

```
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "App",
        //    url: "{*url}",
        //    defaults: new
        //    {
        //        controller = "Home",
        //        action = "Index"
        //    }
        //);
```

please guide me what is the problem for which page refresh is not working. i am looking for a step-by-step help to resolve this problem. i search google but still no luck to get rid of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to learn AngularJS (aka Angular 1) because you were hired to maintain a legacy application? Because if you are learning it in hope to find an AngularJS job, you have to be aware that this library is deprecated since september 2016, when Angular 2 came out. The current version is 13, I believe

Comment: No. our office has a old project where angularjs used. i probably have to work there. so i am trying to get bit familiar with angularjs. my problem is not related with angularjs rather asp.net MVC which blocking page refresh. i tried all the solution searching google. 1) add iis rewrite rule....but no luck. 2) i add catchAll route but still no luck. i am not able to fix this problem from couple of days. nothing is working at my end to get rid of page refresh issue.

Comment: Ah, so indeed it is to maintain a legacy project. Unfortunately, I've forgotten everything about AngularJS since 2016, and I know absolutely nothing of ASP.net, sorry :(

Comment: ok thank you. it will be helpful if some one who work with angularjs & asp.net mvc. then can guide me. thanks

Comment: There must be a difference between the HTTP request that works and the one that 404's. Can you use the Network tab of your browser's dev tools to compare, then update your post?